# Remove Case Sensitivity for Google Storage Bucket as Load Balancer Backend

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, case-sensitive, case-insensitive, google-cloud-load-balancer

We have uploaded our data to a Google Storage Bucket and configured the bucket as the backend of our Google Load Balancer.  Therefore, I can access the files via https://images.mywebsite.com.

However, our file names and directories contain **both upper and lower case characters.**

It appears that Google Storage Buckets are case sensitive, such that if the file is saved as `IMAGE.jpg` and we request `image.jpg` we receive the following error:

> NoSuchKey
>
> > The specified key does not exist.

**Is there any way to remove case sensitivity from our Google Storage Bucket?**  If not, is there any way to resolve this issue such that clients can access our files in a case-insensitive way?

For example, can we rename all the files in our bucket to lowercase, then create some rule on our load balancer to redirect to the lower-case name?

Comment: Did you checked it https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming-objects

Answer (score 1):

There's no feature yet to remove case sensitivity on a Storage bucket but you have an option to rename your objects through `gsutil` or through a Client Library. If you wish to rename your objects programmatically, [here's a good example](https://serverfault.com/a/894804/599396) to start with.

If you don't want that option, as you said, you can also create a host and path rule on your load balancer to redirect your objects to a lowercase prefix but you have to do those manually, if you have a lot of objects to rename, that can be a tedious job.

See https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/l7-internal/traffic-management#routing_requests_to_backends